# node express.js Can't set headers after they are sent.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I am new to both node and express so I figure I am doing something stupid.

Complete source code can be found at:

https://github.com/wa1gon/aclogGate/tree/master/server

```
logRouter.get("/loggate/v1/listall", function(req, res) {
    let countStr = req.param('count');
    let count: number;

    if (!countStr) {
        count = null;
    } else {
        count = Number.parseInt(countStr);
        if (count == NaN) count = null;
    }

    acConn.listAllDatabase(count, (err: string, result: Array<LogGateResp>) => {
        console.log("got list all data resp")
         return res.json(result).end();
    });


    }

    );
    app.use('/', logRouter);
```

It works the first time though, but blows up the second.

listallDatabase connects to a network socket which gets XML database back, parses it and calls back with an JS object. Which in turn calls res.json.

Suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `.end()` after your call to the `json` function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the end() after res.json().

res.josn() send the response to frontend and end() try to send the response again.
That why you are getting the error. Because node.js don't allow the API to send response twice. Either use res.end() or res.json().

Comment: I removed the .end() call but it didn't help.

Comment: The problem seems to be in [link](https://github.com/wa1gon/aclogGate/blob/master/server/aclogApi/AcLogConn.ts)  I am calling logRouter.get('/loggate/va/listall from a net.socket.on callback.  If I get ride of the call back it works.

Comment: The problem seems to be in [aclogApi.ts on gethub](https://github.com/wa1gon/aclogGate/blob/master/server/aclogApi/AcLogConn.ts)  I am calling logRouter.get('/loggate/va/listall from a net.socket.on callback.  If I get ride of the call back it works. I just don't get it.  Surely you can call a callback from a callback.

Comment: Mostly solved.  I rewrote it using just node http without express. Had the same problem found a question in stackoverflow about net.sockets doing the same thing.  Answer was to add a call back to the socket.write to call socket.end();